# Why the init of interface could make an error

Tags: go

I mean the interface could even contain a composite type like struct

```
type A struct {

}
func main() {
    var a interface{} = A{}
}
```

Its weird that interface cant initialize by the brace below this.

```
type C interface {

}
func main() {
    _ = C{}
}
```

Compile result here:invalid composite literal type C

Comment: What do you think this code should do? An interface isn't a struct or map, so the {} don't mean anything here

Answer (score 6):

`C` is an *interface* type and therefore cannot be initialized with a *composite literal*.

> Composite literals construct values for **structs, arrays, slices, and
> maps** and create a new value each time they are evaluated.

https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals

To make the code compile you could do this:

```
type C interface {

}

func main() {
    _ = C(nil)
}
```

Comment: thxxxx,and whats the type about the interface then?

Comment: @hunlin I'm not sure I understand the question, can you try rephrasing it?

Comment: @hunlin note that the `type` keyword, when followed by an identifier and a typespec, is a [type declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_declarations). Note also, as already pointed out in the answer, that not every kind of type can be initialized using the composite literal expression. Those are the rules of the language. That's how the language is defined in the specification. If you find the design weird, if you think it is inconsistent, or you have some other problem with it, you could, if you think it's a good idea, try to raise the issue with the authors of the language.

Comment: @hunlin besides *interface* types there are other types that cannot be initialized with the composite literal expression, for example if you have `type MyString string` you cannot do `_ = MyString{}`. The `type` keyword does not mean that you can use `{}`.

Comment: Thx,man.I have been confused for days on this syntax